# Php scripts not running nor giving error message

Tags: php, linux, command-line, debian

I copied this code from a book i added the

```
<?php
# Initialization
include("LIB_http.php");
include("LIB_parse.php");
$product_array=array();
$product_count=0;

# Download the target (practice store) web page
$target = "http://www.WebbotsSpidersScreenScrapers.com/example_store";
$web_page = http_get($target, "");

# Parse all the tables on the web page into an array
$table_array = parse_array($web_page['FILE'], "<table", "</tables>");

#Look for the the table that contains the product information
for($xx=0; $xx<count($table_array); $xx++)
  {
  $table_landmark = "Products For Sale";
  if(stristr($table_array[$xx], $table_landmark))   // Process this table
    {
    echo "FOUND: Product table\n";


# Parse table into an array of table rows
$product_row_array = parse_array($table_array[$xx], "<tr", "</tr>");
for($table_row=0; $table_row<count($product_row_array); $table_row++)
  {
  # Detect the beginning of the desired data (heading row)
  $heading_landmark = "Condition";
  if((stristr($product_row_array[$table_row], $heading_landmark)))
  {
  echo "FOUND: Talbe heading row\n";

  # Get the position of the desired headings
  $table_cell_array = parse_array($product_row_array[$table_row], "<td", "</td>");
  for($heading_cell=0; $heading_cell<count($table_cell_array); $heading_cell++)
    {
    if(stristr(strip_tags(trim($table_cell_array[$heading_cell])), "ID#"))
      $id_column=$heading_cell;
    if(stristr(strip_tags(trim($table_cell_array[$heading_cell])), "Product name"))
      $name_column=$heading_cell;
    if(stristr(strip_tags(trim($table_cell_array[$heading_cell])), "Price"))
      $price_column=$heading_cell;
    }
  echo "FOUND: id_column=$id_column\n";
  echo "FOUND: price_column=$price_column\n";
  echo "FOUND: name_column=$name_column\n";   

  # Save the heading row for later use

  $heading_row = $table_row;
  }

  #Detect the end of the desired data table
  $ending_landmark = "Calculate";
  if((stristr($product_row_array[$table_row], $ending_landmark)))
    {
    echo "PARSING COMPLETE!\n";
    break;
    }

  # Parse product and price data
  if(isset($heading_row) && $heading_row<$table_row)
    {
    $table_cell_array = parse_array($product_row_array[$table_row], "<td", "</td>");
    $product_array[$product_count]['ID'] = strip_tags(trim($table_cell_array[$id_colum]));
    $product_array[$product_count]['NAME'] = strip_tags(trim($table_cell_array[$name_colum]));
    $product_array[$product_count]['PRICE'] = strip_tags(trim($table_cell_array[$price_colum]));
    $product_count++;
    echo"PROCESSED: Item #$product_count\n";
    }

  #Display the collected data
  for($xx=0; $xx<count($product_array); $xx++)
    {
    echo "$xx. ";
    echo "ID: ".$product_array[$xx]['ID'].", ";
    echo "NAME: ".$product_array[$xx]['NAME'].", ";
    echo "PRICE: ".$product_array[$xx]['PRICE'].", ";
    } 
}
}
}
```

Again the script is giving me no errors but its also not outputting anything.  I'm not sure if I need to add ?> at the end or not.  THis is only my second php script that i have run, so im not sure.

Comment: [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is your friend.

Comment: Turn on error display/logging in your PHP config: `display_errors` and `error_reporting`. And/or put in a bunch of echoes to show what part of the code has been reached.  The error hiding options should NEVER be enabled while developing, since they make it nearly impossible to figure out why something blew up - so once they're turned on, leave them on.

Answer (score 0):

Not in answer to your main problem, I think Marc B answered you well, but since you mentioned it, I'll add that the closing ?> is not required. In fact it can cause "Headers already sent" problems when you have many files and there's blank lines at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This code is from a book called

Webbots, Spiders, and Screen Scrapers: A Guide to Developing Internet Agents with PHP/CURL by Michael Schrenk

the code wasn't working for me at the first time

after checking the code i found that the target address has been changed

replace

$target = "http://www.WebbotsSpidersScreenScrapers.com/example_store";

with

$target = "http://www.webbotsspidersscreenscrapers.com/buyair";